# asp.net Server.Transfer() exception

Tags: asp.net

Why am I getting the exception While executing the Server.Transfer()...

```
Server.Transfer(@"~/Student/StudentSendMail.aspx?username=" + username);

{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}
```

Comment: I don't have any idea what happened. But sometimes, removing try catch block would be a solution. check it.

Comment: This is happening when I am adding a control from an Ajax framework on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cause of this strange error message is performing a Server.Transfer inside of a try-catch block. There are a couple of ways to handle that:

1) Add a second argument set to false like this:

```
Server.Transfer(@"~/Student/StudentSendMail.aspx?username=" + username, false);
```

2) Catch the Exception of type `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` and do nothing in the catch block so the exception is ignored

3) Move the Server.Transfer to the `Finally` block

Comment: the false param isnt related. it existys to preserve form. youre confused with response.reirect boolean

Answer (score -2):

check the below links

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/76bbff0a-da87-4150-a3d1-2a9372e73d81

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/817776da-13da-43f5-a189-1727ce4f3b6b

http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/11/15/funceval-rules.aspx