# ThreadAbortException in server transfer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting error `Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.` while executing line

```
Server.Transfer("Payment.aspx?vpc_ChannelId=2", true);
```

so as pointed out by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252119/1169180 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130517/1169180

i changed my code to

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    UserContext conObj = new UserContext();
    HttpContext CurrContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Code
    }
    else
    {
        string userContext = hdnContextObj.Value;
        conObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserContext>(userContext);
        CurrContext.Items.Add("Context", conObj);
        try
        {
        Server.Transfer("Payment.aspx?vpc_ChannelId=2", true);
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException xObj)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        Server.Transfer("Payment.aspx?vpc_ChannelId=2", true);
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception xObj)
    {
    Response.Write("Exception : " + xObj.Message);
    }
}
```

still i am getting same exception in out catch block

Also as pointed out here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/ i used `Server.Execute` but it didnt redirect to `Payment.aspx` page instead it just refreshes.

Comment: Your try/catch is does not do anything, you are catching and then reshowing the same exception, this is the same as not catching it at all. If you want to swallow the exception then don't throw in your catch block.

Comment: @BenRobinson : even if i remove throw from catch block. when line in finally gets executed, exception gets catched outer most catch block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is raised because the thread running the operation is forced to terminate in multiple locations due to the transfer.  As such, it is safe to ignore this exception as your linked answers suggest.

You can ignore the exception by catching the exception and not throwing it.

```
try
{
    Server.Transfer("Payment.aspx?vpc_ChannelId=2", true);
}
catch(ThreadAbortException)
{
    // Exception ignored: Thread Abort = discontinue processing on the current page
}
```

Alternatively, as the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849(v=vs.90).aspx) article suggest, you can use `Server.Execute` instead.

> To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:
>
> - For `Response.End`, call the `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` method instead of `Response.End` to bypass the code execution to the `Application_EndRequest` event.
> - For `Response.Redirect`, use an overload, `Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse)` that passes `false` for the `endResponse` parameter to suppress the internal call to `Response.End`. For example:
>
>   ```
>     Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);
>   ```
>
>   If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed.
> - **For `Server.Transfer`, use the `Server.Execute` method instead.**

// Clarification on `Server.Execute`

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac8t9s7b(v=vs.110).aspx) doc clarifies the usage of `Server.Execute`.  It is important to remember this is not a redirect, it acts like a function call.  So any code after the call will also be executed.  If you do not want the code to execute you can use a `return`, or `Response.End`.

In the OP's example, his code might look something like this when using `Server.Execute`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       UserContext conObj = new UserContext();
       HttpContext CurrContext = HttpContext.Current;
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
           // Code
       }
       else
       {
           string userContext = hdnContextObj.Value;
           conObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserContext>(userContext);
           CurrContext.Items.Add("Context", conObj);
           Server.Execute("Payment.aspx?vpc_ChannelId=2", true);
           Response.End(); // or return;
       }
    }
    catch (Exception xObj)
    {
       Response.Write("Exception : " + xObj.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both your solution suggested `Server.Execute` doesnt redirect my page & when the finally block gets executed it further throws exception

Comment: @Shaggy I have added an example.  Remember, `Server.Execute` works like a function call, it will return control back to the executing application.  So, you need to manually end the response or break out of a procedure.

Comment: now on `Response.End()` it throwing same error after using `Server.Execute`

Comment: @Shaggy . . . I do not have your code here, so I cannot envision every single error that might occur.  As suggested, use `return` instead.

Comment: @Shaggy I think I might not be explaining this clearly.  If you need a redirect, use `Server.Transfer` with empty `catch`, if you need the code to run from the other page, use `Server.Execute`.

Answer (score 0):

> Server.Transfer("Payment.aspx?vpc_ChannelId=2", false);

This will work for you. It stops the rest of the remaining code after the transfer code, so that it will not execute that code.

Comment: i want to preserve form data. so true is required.

Comment: Okay, but can we see the rest of the code? Cause it is most likely that that is what causes this problem

Answer (score 0):

ThreadAbortException exception caused because Response.End called both in Server.Redirect and  Server.Transfer internally.Try something like this

```
    Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.href = 'Your.aspx'; </script>");
```

Comment: I want to preserve `context` object. so server.transfer which i wanted